# C++20 modules with cmake + ninja

Tags: cmake, c++20, ninja, c++-modules

Where can I find an example of how to build a C++20 module using cmake + ninja?

*hello.mpp*

```
export module hello;
export int i = 42;
```

*main.cpp:*

```
import hello;

#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::cout << i;
}
```

What should I write in CMakeLists.txt to build this? I need a cross platform solution

Comment: Have you searched for your topic before asking the question? If yes, the I wonder how have you missed already existed questions.